# laravel backpack user password

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

I made a crud for my users in backpack. When I create a user everything works fine but if I update I get an error for "Password" since if I dont want to update it I leave it blank and password cannot be null.

How can I not add "password" to the POST if I leave it blank? Or how do I default to the current password?? and also have a "confirm" field?

In UserCrudController.php

```
<?php 

    namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

    use Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\CrudController;
    use App\User;
    use Auth;

    // VALIDATION: change the requests to match your own file names if you need form validation
    use App\Http\Requests\UserCrudRequest as StoreRequest;
    use App\Http\Requests\UserCrudRequest as UpdateRequest;

    class UserCrudController extends CrudController {

        public function setup() {
            $this->crud->setModel("App\User");
            $this->crud->setRoute(config('backpack.base.route_prefix')."/user");
            $this->crud->setEntityNameStrings('user', 'users');

            $this->crud->setColumns([
                ['name' => 'lastname', 'label' => "Last Name"],
                ['name' => 'firstname', 'label' => "First Name"],

            ]);


            $this->crud->addFields([
                [
                    'name' => 'firstname',
                    'label' => "First name"
                ],
                [
                    'name' => 'lastname',
                    'label' => "First name"
                ],


                    [   // Password
                        'name' => 'password',
                        'label' => 'Password',
                        'type' => 'password'
                    ],

            ]);


        }

        public function store(StoreRequest $request)
        {
            // <---------  here is where a before_insert callback logic would be

            $response = parent::storeCrud();

            // <---------  here is where a after_insert callback logic would be

            return $response;
        }

        public function update(UpdateRequest $request)
        {
            $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);

            // Hash password before save
            if (!empty($request->password)) {
                $request->offsetSet('password', Hash::make($request->password));
            }else{
                $request->offsetSet('password', $user->password );
            }

            return parent::updateCrud();
        }
    }
```

Error:

```
 Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'password' cannot be null (SQL: update `users` set `password` = , `updated_at` = 2017-10-06 15:08:25 where `id` = 1)
```

Comment: show me your controler method and form

Comment: @iCoders I added the fill Controller. Again I am using Backpack for my CRUD. https://laravel-backpack.readme.io/docs

Comment: can you dd($request->all()); and show output and also print Auth::user()

Comment: I found the right way to do it looking at their CRUD for a Permissions Manager

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is making their own UserCrudController for Backpack look at their controller they did for a permissions manager:

https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/PermissionManager/blob/master/src/app/Http/Controllers/UserCrudController.php

Answer (score 0):

you can try remove password like this :

```
           // Hash password before save
        if (!empty($request->password)) {
            $request->offsetSet('password', Hash::make($request->password));
        }else{
             $request->remove('password');
        }
```