# Laravel Backpack creating User

Tags: laravel, passwords, laravel-backpack, password-confirmation

When creating a User with Backpack's CRUD, how can I add a field in setupCreateOperation for both my password and the password confirmation?
I know I can add a field for the password in multiple ways, for example

```
CRUD::addField([
    'name' => 'password',
    'label' => 'Password',
    'type' => 'password',
]);
```

but how can I add a second field for password confirmation and use it just in the validation without persisting it to the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I solved this basically adding a custom store method and removing the 'password_confirmation' field from the request, I found this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46608870/laravel-backpack-user-password)